# How to add value to a custom column while uploading document into a SharePoint document library as an item using C#?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have a console application which tries to upload a document into a share point document library list.

I am successfully able to do it and also I am able to fill one of the custom Column(Column name is : "Category") value while uploading the file using C#.

I have tried to fill another custom column(Column name is : "Related Assets") value using the same procedure but i get the error stating the provided column name does not exist but when i see in actual share point portal it does exist.

So not able to solve this issue. Even i tried couple of methods as given below and i get same error message in terms of the column does not exist or it has been deleted or not able to recognize it.

Please find the screenshot of SharePoint showing the list of columns:

[image]

Please find the code i have till now which upload the document into SharePoint portal.

```
public static async Task<string> UploadReleaseNoteDocumentintoSpPortal(string releasenotefilepath, string releasenotefilename, string clientid, string clientsecret)
        {
            string status = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Trying to Upload Release note file into  Share Point Portal...");
                
                string siteUrl = "<<Sp site URL>>";

                Console.WriteLine("Connecting to Share Point Portal...");
                var ClientContext = new OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager().GetAppOnlyAuthenticatedContext(siteUrl, clientid, clientsecret);
                ClientContext.Load(ClientContext.Web, p => p.Title);
                await ClientContext.ExecuteQueryAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(ClientContext.Web.Title);
                var web = ClientContext.Web;
                Console.WriteLine("Connected successfully to Share Point Portal...");

                List DocumentsList = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Accelerators Documents");
                ClientContext.Load(DocumentsList.RootFolder);
                await ClientContext.ExecuteQueryAsync();
                Console.WriteLine("Reading and loading the list named : Accelerators Documents from SP");

                Console.WriteLine("Converting the release note document into byte array");
                byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(releasenotefilepath);
              
                MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);

                Console.WriteLine("Storing the release note Data into File Create information object of SharePoint");
                FileCreationInformation FileCreateInfo = new FileCreationInformation();
                FileCreateInfo.Content = bytes;
                FileCreateInfo.ContentStream = stream;
                FileCreateInfo.Overwrite = true;
                FileCreateInfo.Url = DocumentsList.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + @"\" + releasenotefilename;

                Console.WriteLine("Adding file to  SharePoint");
                var ReleaseNoteFiledata = DocumentsList.RootFolder.Files.Add(FileCreateInfo);
                ReleaseNoteFiledata.Update();
                ReleaseNoteFiledata.ListItemAllFields["Category"] = "Release Notes";
        //ReleaseNoteFiledata.ListItemAllFields["Related Assets"] = "<<Desired Value>>"; 
                //IN Above commented line i get the error stating Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException: 
        //'Column 'Related Assets' does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user.  
        //But in actual site if we see it exists as you can see in above screenshot
                ReleaseNoteFiledata.ListItemAllFields.Update();
                ClientContext.Load(ReleaseNoteFiledata);
                await ClientContext.ExecuteQueryAsync();

                Console.WriteLine("Adding file to SharePoint Completed Successfully...");
                return status = "Successful";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception occured while trying to upload Release note file into CoP Portal :" + ex.Message);
                return status = "Error/Exception";
            }
        }
```

Please find the error message i get while trying to add value to another custom column present in SharePoint:
**Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException: 'Column 'Related Assets' does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user.**

Even if i use the `ReleaseNoteFiledata.SetFileProperties()` and pass the values as a dictionary key value pair containing the column name and its value then also i get the same error for the second custom column. If i keep only the category custom column then it works perfectly without any issue as you can see in the screenshot above.

If i select the record and see the details or properties in the SharePoint the Related assets column symbol is some like in below screenshot:

[image]

Please let me know if the supporting documents are fine or still if my issue is not understandable so that i can re frame it or provide more screenshots.

Please help me in solving the above issue or how to make this column recognizable or readable or identifiable in the code.

Thanks in Advance

Regards

ChaitanyaNG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the internal name of the column 'Related Assets' in your code. It should be `Related_x0020_Assets`.

You could check the internal name of the column by go to list settings-> click the column, you would see the internal name in the url.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your inputs now i understood where the issue is and where to look into for these type of columns. This worked. Thanks again for your time.